# Plot Multiple Graph in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I know how to [plot a graph in google spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/583/how-to-plot-time-series-graph-in-google-spreadsheet). But how to plot multiple graphs, with different X and Y values in  Google Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `plot multiple graphs, with different X and Y values` can be achieved in New Google Sheets:

[image: WA4923 example]

but with what appears to be very limited scope for tailoring the result to suit (relative even to Excel).

Answer (score 0):

By multiple graphs do you mean multiple axes on the same graph? If so this is not the answer you were hoping for, but it currently can't be done :(  Hopefully they will add this feature soon.

You can plot multiple axes using the [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/chart_params.html), but that probably isn't useful to you.